# Pass anonymous multiline function as an argument to another function

Tags: powershell

Suppose there is a function that getting two functions as a parameters:

```
function do_until([scriptblock] $f, [scriptblock] $p, [System.TimeSpan] $timeout = (New-Timespan -Minutes 5), [System.TimeSpan] $delay = (New-Timespan -Seconds 5))
{
    $timer = [diagnostics.stopwatch]::StartNew()
    do
    {
        $f.Invoke()
        Start-Sleep $delay.Seconds
    } until ($p.Invoke() -or $timer.elapsed -ge $timeout)
}
```

This works:

```
do_until { "hi!" } { 1 -gt 2 } (New-Timespan -Seconds 10) (New-Timespan -Seconds 1)
```

This fails

```
do_until 
{ 
    "hi!" 
    "and again!"
} { 1 -gt 2 } (New-Timespan -Seconds 10) (New-Timespan -Seconds 1)
```

with error

```
At C:\c\powershell\functions.ps1:15 char:3
+ } { 1 -gt 2 } (New-Timespan -Seconds 10) (New-Timespan -Seconds 1)
+   ~
Unexpected token '{' in expression or statement.
At C:\c\powershell\functions.ps1:15 char:15
+ } { 1 -gt 2 } (New-Timespan -Seconds 10) (New-Timespan -Seconds 1)
+               ~
Unexpected token '(' in expression or statement.
At C:\c\powershell\functions.ps1:15 char:42
+ } { 1 -gt 2 } (New-Timespan -Seconds 10) (New-Timespan -Seconds 1)
+                                          ~
Unexpected token '(' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

How to pass this anonymous multiline function as an argument to `do_until`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PowerShell is interpreting `do_until` as a complete command on a line of its own. Instead:

1) Start the scriptblock on the same line as the function call (an opening `{` does not form a complete expression, so PowerShell will continue parsing to the following lines).

```
do_until {
  "hi!"
  "and again!"
} { 1 -gt 2 } (New-Timespan -Seconds 10) (New-Timespan -Seconds 1)
```

2) Use the `` ` `` escape character to inform PowerShell about the multi-line command.

```
do_until `
{
  "hi!"
  "and again!"
} { 1 -gt 2 } (New-Timespan -Seconds 10) (New-Timespan -Seconds 1)
```

3) Save the scriptblock to a variable before calling the function (like an opening `{`, PowerShell will continue parsing after an incomplete `=` assignment).

```
$action =
{
  "hi!"
  "and again!"
}

do_until $action { 1 -gt 2 } (New-Timespan -Seconds 10) (New-Timespan -Seconds 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two options:

1) Use the line continuation character ` (backtick), e.g.:

```
do_until `
{ 
    "hi!" 
    "and again!"
} { 1 -gt 2 } (New-Timespan -Seconds 10) (New-Timespan -Seconds 1)
```

2) Don't put the opening curly brace on it's own line, e.g.:

```
do_until { 
    "hi!" 
    "and again!"
} { 1 -gt 2 } (New-Timespan -Seconds 10) (New-Timespan -Seconds 1)
```

I prefer the second option because the backtick is hard to see sometimes.